# yum list available - not showing all packages

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm

I have a strange problem with yum, working on one server and not working on another server that *should* be identical.

The symptom is that after running createrepo on a directory containing RPMs (and creating a definition called "foo" in /etc/yum.repos.d):

```
yum list available --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=foo
```

shows all 23 RPMs on one server, but only 7 of them on the other.

On the server that only shows 7 RPMs, I can still see the missing RPMs by running

```
yum search <package_name> --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=foo
```

I have checked:

- SELinux - disabled on both servers
- OS Version - RHEL 6.4 on both
- Kernel - same on both
- Version of Yum and createrepo command

So, what could be different between the servers to create this problem?

Comment: what yum plugins do you have installed?

Comment: What's the repolist in both machines ?

Comment: Did you try running `yum clean all` on the problematic server?

Answer (score 10):

If the package is installed, it will not show up as available.  You can specify the `--showduplicates` option to see everything that is available in a repo whether it is installed or not.  I would suggest comparing output of the following command run on both servers.  It should be the same output if both servers are accessing the same repo:

```
yum list available --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=foo --showduplicates
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try this

```
yum list --showduplicates | grep foo
```

The "yum list" lists all packages installed or available the "--showduplicates" shows all packages in all enabled repos even if they have been seen in another repo then just grep for your repo name to see what is being provided by your local repo

Answer (score 0):

`yum list available` won't show packages that already installed on this system.

Try this:

- list all packages from specific repo (include installed):

```bash
sudo yum repo-pkgs "<repo name>" list
```

- list installed packages from specific repo:

```bash
sudo yum repo-pkgs "<repo name>" list installed
```